VsCode c# dev extension reverts text color
I created a .net project in vs-code. In the last few days, every time I open a .cs file, everything looks fine at the first glance; but, a few seconds later, it all changes. It looks like the following screenshots.
I can't figure out what's happening.
fine:

broken:

